# ARCore 3D object display

Tags: android, arcore

I am a complete beginner with ARCore and I would like to ask if it is possible to display 3D objects using 3D coordinates and having the user as the origin? For example, having (x,y,z) values of (0,3,0) will display the 3D object to the right of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: **There is no native implementation in ARCore for that!**.

But you're not completely lost. There are some very useful libraries in **Android** like [appoly](https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location). I've used this fork from [Eric Neidhardt](https://github.com/EricNeid/arcore-location-extension).

For **iOS** I only know [this](https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation) library based on ARKit.

You can also make a Unity3D app in C# and use [AR Foundation and Vuforia Plug-in](https://docs.unity-ar-gps-location.com/#main-features). This way is platform-independent, but imho testing is a pain.

You see, there are a few options out there, but **be careful that none is really accurate!**

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It seems that I was limiting myself to a solution that uses native implementation.

Comment: Note that the accuracy can be wrong by a hundred meters. In my experience, however, it is usually 5 to 10 meters. The inaccuracy comes rather from the compass than the GNSS. I am always happy to get an upvote or accepted answer if I could help you.